# Node.js service for put operation

Tags: json, node.js

Hello I want to put operation in a JSON format . Probably My JSON parse error so that I can't able to update Data . My JSON body data is

```
[{
  "receiptNo": "21456",
  "rollno": 12201,
  "bankcode": 2,
  "userid": "rifat",
  "__v": "0"
}]
```

And my NodeJS code :

```
router.put('/receiptmaster1/update/:receiptNo', function (req,res) {
  receipt_master1.updateMany({ 
    receiptNo: req.params.receiptNo 
  }, {
    receiptNo: req.body.receiptNo,
    rollno: req.body.rollno,
    bankcode : req.body.bankcode,
    userid: 'rifat',
    __v: "0"
  }).then(function(err) {
    res.send({
      success: true,
      message: "Updated Successfully Master2"
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: err.message || "Error while Updating Server Data"
    });
  });
});
```

My data is not updated though I have got this response

```
"success":true,"message":"Updated Successfully Master2"
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is a single object in an array. Either change the posted format to be an object (without the wrapping array) when you send it:

```
{
  "receiptNo": "21456",
  "rollno": 12201,
  "bankcode": 2,
  "userid": "rifat",
  "__v": "0"
}
```

or change how you access it on the server:

```
router.put('/receiptmaster1/update/:receiptNo', function (req,res) {
  receipt_master1.updateMany({ 
    receiptNo: req.params.receiptNo 
  }, {
    receiptNo: req.body[0].receiptNo,
    rollno: req.body[0].rollno,
    bankcode : req.body[0].bankcode,
    userid: 'rifat',
    __v: "0"
  }).then(function(err) {
    res.send({
      success: true,
      message: "Updated Successfully Master2"
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: err.message || "Error while Updating Server Data"
    });
  });
});
```

Note the change from `req.body.` to `req.body[0].`